# K-equivalence ⇒ isomorphism of Chow motives?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, derived-categories, motives

An old conjecture of Bondal–Orlov–Kawamata predicts that K-equivalent varieties are D-equivalent, see Kawamata's paper [D-equivalence and K-equivalence](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0205287) for definitions. In particular this applies to birational Calabi–Yau varieties. See [Progress on Bondal–Orlov derived equivalence conjecture](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/334314/progress-on-bondal-orlov-derived-equivalence-conjecture) for the Bondal–Orlov formulation of the conjecture and the known cases. These conjectures are mostly open, and considered to be an important bridge between derived categories and birational geometry.

Derived categories and Chow motives play the role of universal cohomology theories, in noncommutative, and commutative worlds respectively. Do we expect that *K-equivalence implies isomorphism of rational, or even integral Chow motives*?

**Example 1.** Integral Chow motives of varieties related by a standard flop are isomorphic: [Q. Jiang - On the Chow theory of projectivization](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.06730). This was the motivation for the question.

**Example 2** (from Nico Berger's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/381857/k-equivalence-isomorphism-of-chow-motives#comment970805_381857)). Birational irreducible holomorphic symplectic varieties have isomorphic integral Chow motives: [U. Riess - On the Chow ring of birational irreducible symplectic varieties](http://arxiv.org/abs/1304.4404).

**Remarks.** In many cases, D-equivalence is known to imply isomorphisms for rational Chow motives, but not  for integral ones: examples can be found among K3 surfaces. It is also known that D-equivalence *does not* imply K-equivalence, even for rational surfaces: [Uehara - An example of Fourier–Mukai partners of minimal elliptic surfaces](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0312499).

Comment: I am a bit puzzled by your last remark: for K3 surfaces, D-equivalence implies indeed isomorphism of Chow motives — this is a result of Huybrechts (Abh. Math. Semin. Univ. Hambg. 88 (2018), no. 1, 201–207).

Comment: @abx: Read carefully; Huybrechts considers rational Chow motives.

Comment: Riess proved that K-equivalent (i.e. birational) irreducible holomorphic symplectic varieties have isomorphic integral Chow motives, see https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.4404.

Comment: @crystalline: Yes indeed, thanks — I was misled by the statement of Theorem 1.1 in Huybrechts' paper. Doesn't "Chow motive" usually refer to the integral ones?

Comment: There is an upgrade of Huybrechts' result by Fu-Vial stating that the rational Chow motives of derived equivalent K3 surfaces are isomorphic as "Frobenius algebra objects", see https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.10868. Their Question 1 asks for the case of ihs manifolds.

Comment: @abx: I agree with that, but my confidence in Evgeny's expertise on this topic led me to double check Huybrechts' statement more carefully.

Comment: It appears that if we had a version of motivic integration with values in  $K_0(Chow)$ then the D-equivalence of X and Y would imply that $M(X)\bigoplus Z\cong M(Y)\bigoplus Z$ for some Chow motif Z.  Assuming some motivic conjecture one would obtain that $M(X)\cong M(Y)$ for motives with rational coefficients, but not with integral ones.

Comment: @Mickhail Bondarko: I think we know $[M(X)] = [M(Y)]$ in $K_0(Chow) \otimes \mathbf{Q}$.

Answer (score 4):

**K-equivalence $\implies$ isomorphism of (rational) Chow motives** is a conjecture going back to [this 2002 paper of Wang](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/journal-of-differential-geometry/volume-60/issue-2/Cohomology-Theory-in-Birational-Geometry/10.4310/jdg/1090351105.full) (Conjecture 2.2); see [this overview paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0204160.pdf) of his for what else K-equivalence should imply on the cohomological level.

Some important special cases, such as ordinary flops and Mukai flops are proven in [this 2010 paper by Lee, Lin and Wang](https://annals.math.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/annals-v172-n1-p05-s.pdf). In 2016 the case of semismall K-equivalences has been proved by [Liu: "Motivic equivalence under semismall flops"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.06152.pdf).